# Better way to check if JSON value is defined?

Tags: javascript

I am using an API call to return JSON data which I then write to a model. If the value doesn't exist I get an error, so I have to check it's valid first. Is there a better way than to have to write custom validation for each different value?

```
const agentName = (record.brokers && record.brokers.length) && record.brokers[0].agent;
const agentEmail = (record.brokers && record.brokers.length && record.brokers[0].emails && record.brokers[0].emails.length) && record.brokers[0].emails[0];
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
const email = (typeof record.brokers[0].emails[0] !== 'undefined') && record.brokers[0].emails[0];
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using something like `lodash` in your project, there's a `get` function for `object`s with nested properties that could get you what you need - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.get, see docs here - https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the shortcut is kinda weird but useful, use || and make blank objects/arrays.

```
const agentName = ((record.brokers || [])[0] || {}).agent;
const agentEmail = (((record.brokers || [])[0] || {}).emails || [])[0];
```

But I like the most is using `lodash`, `_.get` is all you need.

```
_.get(record, 'brokers.0.agent');
_.get(record, 'brokers.0.emails.0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try/catch block?

Rather than manually validating every field, treat it as valid until an exception is thrown.

```
var valid = true;
try {
    var agentName= record.brokers[0].agent;
    var agentEmail = record.brokers[0].emails[0];
    valid = false;
} catch(err) {
   console.log("Invalid record");        
}

if (valid) {
   // continue processing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use **lodash**. It is a utility library and mainly used for this purpose only.
Your lengthy code can be shortened into the following

```js
let _ = require('lodash')
// this will return undefined if it agent name is not present. Thus helps it to write short conditions.
const agentName = _.get(record, ['brokers', 0 , 'agent'])
// similarly this will also help you to write short and better conditions.
// you can also use third parameters for defaults.
const agentEmail = _.get(record, ['brokers', 0, 'emails', 0])
// you can use something like this 

if (agentEmail) //for handling the not null condition 
{
/* your logic here */
}
```

You can read more about [lodash here](https://lodash.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check [object-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path). It can handle what you need and even more.